# Which is the most widely used EOS android app?

Tags: android, lynx-wallet, meet.one-wallet

I only know of 2 eos wallets for android: lynx and meet.one

Is there another one that is reputable and has many installs? I want to go with a reliable developer that isn't going to steal your funds. I like that lynx is based out of USA, but meet.one seems to be based out of asia. Which ones or others would be more reliable and trustworthy from a community perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out EOS REACH, it is the only open source Android wallet.

- [App on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.memtrip.eosreach)
- [Source code on github](https://github.com/memtrip/eosreach-android)

Open source wallets are the only safe way to store your funds, if a security vulnerability is found in the code it will be highlighted by the community immediately.